# Use Wordpress-shell and write custom post types

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to use Wordpress as a CMS-solution, and I've noticed a few solutions looks like this back-end:

[image]

The case here is that it seems like there's just the basic WP-functions on the site, while things like "hjem", "Fakta" etc are custom made post types.

These post types can be added in posts, which then again results in different design elements like images, fact boxes, stats etc.

Does anyone know how to do this? Create custom post types, call them something and save them for use in posts?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: Start by looking at tutorials on how to work with custom post types. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/ is one place to start. (or https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/complete-guide-custom-post-types/). Lykke til :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this manually, I recommend you to check [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Or you can register custom post types through this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/).